# Feathersjs-Mongoose populate data

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs

When using find method, how can populate data from other collection. The join operation that we do with sql databases. Right now i am using something like :
code:

```
async find(data, params) {
    let records = await super.find(data, params);
    let newrecords = records.data.map(async (user) => {
      let professordetails = await this.app
        .service("users")
        .get(user.professorId);
      professordetails.password = undefined;
      user.professorId = professordetails;
      return user;
    });
    return await Promise.all(newrecords).then((completed) => {
      return completed;
    });
  }
```

This is course service and its model :

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const modelName = "courses";
  const mongooseClient = app.get("mongooseClient");
  const { Schema } = mongooseClient;
  const { ObjectId } = Schema;
  const schema = new Schema(
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      details: { type: String, required: true },
      professorId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "users", required: true },
      enrolledStudents: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );
  // This is necessary to avoid model compilation errors in watch mode
  // see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-deleteModel
  if (mongooseClient.modelNames().includes(modelName)) {
    mongooseClient.deleteModel(modelName);
  }
  return mongooseClient.model(modelName, schema);
};
```

This is something like a unwanted operation as we are having populate. But i couldn't do it with populate.

Comment: I guess it might be an issue with the way you are creating data records. Could you show me how you are creating records? Maybe we could figure out what's wrong.

Comment: For creating data I am using the default feathersjs serivice routes. And I am not touching anything on create method. Just passing preofessor id and i have specified reference for professor id in course model. So this is what happening here!